# Poset is complete iff it is cocomplete

Tags: category-theory, boolean-algebra

In Awodey's Category Theory, page 130, he says:

> A poset is (co)-complete if it is so as a category, thus if it has all set-indexed meets (resp. joins). For posets, completeness and cocompleteness are equivalent. A lattice, Heyting algebra, Boolean algebra, etc. is called *complete* if it is so as a poset.

As an example, I'll take the poset $\omega$, which is well-ordered. A subset of a well-ordered set has a least element, so $\omega$ has all meets.

However, $\omega$ itself (as a subset of $\omega$) has no join. Indeed, a join would be $a$ such that for all $c \in \omega$, have "all $a_i \leq c$" iff $a \leq c$. Since there is no $c \in \omega$ such that for all $a_i \in \omega$, $a_i \leq c$, we must therefore have $a \not \leq c$ for all $c \in \omega$. But no $a$ has this property, so $\omega$ doesn't have a join.

In summary, $\omega$ has all meets, but doesn't have all joins. That is, it is complete but not cocomplete.

What have I done wrong? Awodey makes the distinction between a Boolean algebra and a poset here, so we don't necessarily have access to the nice properties of Boolean algebras.

Comment: You need to consider degenerate cases like nullary meets/joins. $\omega$ does not even have finite meets: it does not have a maximum element.

Comment: In fact, a category has finite products iff it has binary products *and* a terminal object (AKA the empty product).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a preordered set $(X,\le)$, a maximum element (which is the same thing as a terminal object in the associated category) can be described either as the infimum of the empty system or as the supremum of all elements of $X$. This shows that $\omega$, which lacks a maximum element, is neither complete nor cocomplete as a category.

This is due to the observation, that when checking universal properties in [thin categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/thin+category), uniqueness of the induced arrows is for free. That is, a terminal object $t$ is characterized by the existence of some arrow $x\longrightarrow t$ for all objects $x$. Both, $t$ being the product of the empty family, and $t$ being the coproduct of all objects, ensure this condition.

Answer (score 0):

It might be interesting to say that in **Cocompleteness almost implies completeness** Adamek et al. proved the following.

> Any cocomplete weakly co-wellpowered category with a weakly colimit-dense small subcategory is complete.

A (kind of-)dual statement holds for completeness.

Comment: Could you please give me a reference to this result? I'm kind of interested in this

Comment: https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1047905

I am sorry, I can't do better than this link. The paper is hard to find, I suggest to ask to your library.